# Firefox right button on selected text start Inspect Tool not right button menu

Tags: firefox, menu

I test Elementary OS 5.0 (Juno). When I use Firefox and select some text press right button I get strange behavior. I do not see the menu but I see the Inspect tool from Firefox.

My question is this normal and is there a settings for that to change to the normal menu?

Answer (score 3):

I confirm the same behaviour, but don't believe it to be a Linux issue, rather a Firefox issue/setting upstream.

**Solution:**

1. Open new tab in Firefox and type `about:config` in the address bar.
2. Accept the warning displayed.
3. Search for `ui.context_menus.after_mouseup`.
4. Change it from `false` to `true`.
5. Close tab and test.

**References:**

I stumbled on the solution above @ [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/8uyoic/unwanted_context_menu_behaviour_after_update_to/).

Answer (score 0):

I have also this problem in firefox 62 (not in chrome and not in epiphany) its in juno Beta 1 and 2.. and also got this bug in nighly build of firefox too.

I don't know how to fix this but if you hold the right mouse button for few seconds you can use the right mouse button menu..

But this bug need to fixed by Elementary os Juno. (this bug is not in Loki)