# Firefox Context Menus are weird and don't work correctly

Tags: mouse, pantheon, release-juno, firefox, context-menu

I'm having an issue where I right click and as soon as I release the button, it selects the option where the mouse is like I left-clicked. Also, context menus are appearing in the middle of where my mouse is. Attached is an imaged that shows what I'm saying:
[image: See the mouse in the middle of the context menu?]

Comment: I had this problem. Rebooting the pc solved it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is an firefox bug or not but there are more topics about this

[Firefox right button on selected text start Inspect Tool not right button menu](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16332/firefox-right-button-on-selected-text-start-inspect-tool-not-right-button-menu/16341#16341)

and [Firefox right click issue](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16475/firefox-right-click-issue)

Also what version of firefox are you using? I have version 62.03 and got no problems with the mouse button/context menu for now.

Edit: got a litte fix go to -> about:config and change ui.context_menus.after_mouseup to true This fix the problem for now

Comment: I confirm this bug with Pantheon packages on openSUSE Leap 15.1 and Firefox 60 ESR. The about:config fix works.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exact problem on my laptop. The roundabout way is to HOLD the right-click on a MOUSE. Then the menu stays open and you can select the proper option.
Quite frustrating, TBH. FF 62.0.3