# Firefox right click issue

Tags: firefox

is anybody else having this annoying issue with Firefox? 
when I right-click the little window that pops-up clashes with the mouse, making it difficult to *choose* what to select.

Comment: Yes. I have it too. Also with Tor browser which I think uses firefox under the hood. It is a pretty anoying issue. I had it after installing firefox on my new juno install. Which version of elementary are you running, @Vincenzo?

Comment: i thinks your answer is here https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/17101/mouse-right-click-double-clicks

Answer (score 11):

As user **pole** mentioned above, the answer can be found here:
[mouse right click double clicks?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/17101/mouse-right-click-double-clicks)

In the Firefox address bar, type `about:config`.

Go to `ui.context_menus.after_mouseup` and set it to `true`.

Hat tip to user **WebShaped.Biz** for providing the answer.

Comment: While this "fixes" the issue of accidentally "clicking" whichever right click menu is under the mouse at the time that you release the right click, it still doesn't actually fix the issue of the cursor appearing right in the middle of the popup menu. The popup menus should open to the immediate bottom right of the mouse, like every other context menu in every other application. Something is wrong with Firefox on Elementary (or possibly on Linux in general). This doesn't happen in Windows with the same FF version, and coincidentally, this about:config option is set to false (the default) in Win

Comment: I confirm this bug with Pantheon packages on openSUSE Leap 15.1 and Firefox 60 ESR. The `about:config` fix that @Paul mentions worked.

Comment: Thanks Paul this worked for me too. @vincenzo_nardelli - how about you mark this answer to Paul for describing how to fix this?