# mouse right click double clicks?

Tags: release-juno, firefox, epiphany

[image]

I have an annoying issue with Firefox and epiphany when I right click on a link to open it in a new tab, it does not give me the chance to click it, it clicks by it self I have to hold the right click to select what I want, some times it goes back to normal and I just right click and the menu stays there but most of the time I have this problem the menu just clicks on the first thing it hovers over in the menu . idk what to do anymore

Answer (score 8):

For the right-click mouse fix of Firefox, type in the search bar `about:config` and change `ui.context_menus.after_mouseup` to `true`

Comment: I'd vote this up twice if I could. That was an annoying issue! Thanks for this fix

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is **disabling the title bar** in Firefox's Customize mode - this will fix the issue and also brings window controls and tabs next to each other and thus making more space available for the website.

Source: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/9ucdxd/firefox_right_click_context_menu_gets_activated/e936sw5)