# Context menu opens with the mouse pointer in the middle of it

Tags: firefox, context-menu

Beginning early this past week sometime I noticed the right-click context menu in Firefox opens with the mouse pointer right in the middle of it. As a result it usually selects "Inspect Element" immediately, when what I want is to select "Search Yahoo for 'selected word'".

This doesn't happen when using Chromium or Chrome on the same computer and same user. I reset Firefox, but that didn't fix it. I removed Firefox and and the .mozilla folder from my home directory, then reinstalled Firefox and tested before syncing with my Firefox account. It still behaved the same way.

I created a new user in the OS and tested with the same results.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed the unintended selecting for me, but not the menu placement https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/17297/18379

Comment: Thanks for the link. This prevents the issue and it is less annoying, if not fixed. Here is the change:

In the Firefox address bar, type about:config.

Go to ui.context_menus.after_mouseup and set it to true.